# Node.js can't connect to Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

I am new to Node.js. So I tried the parse-example to connect my Node.js app with a Mongo DB. So after I installed everything, changed the Master and the AppID (in the Index.js and script.js), I tried to start my app (npm start) and then these Warning appears.

```
>     > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-e
>     xample
>     > node index.js
>     
>     DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.
>     parse-server-example running on port 1337.
>     info: Parse LiveQuery Server starts running
>     warn: Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames:  MongoError: failed to connect
>     to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
>         at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-example\nod
>     e_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:313:35
>     )
>         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>         at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
>         at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-examp
>     le\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:26
>     0:12)
>         at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
>         at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>         at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
>         at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-example\n
>     ode_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:
>     162:49)
>         at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
>         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     warn: Unable to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses:  MongoError: failed
>     to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
>         at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-example\nod
>     e_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:313:35
>     )
>         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>         at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
>         at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-examp
>     le\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:26
>     0:12)
>         at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
>         at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>         at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
>         at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TAASCTI5\temp\parseex\parse-server-example\n
>     ode_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:
>     162:49)
>         at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
>         at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     (node:18132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
>     ction id: 4): MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first
>      connect
>     (node:18132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
>     ction id: 5): MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first
>      connect
```

The result is that i can't connect to my Mongo DB with an Error 500 internal Server Error.

Comment: You need to post your code as well... But it looks like you don't have mongodb running locally on your computer. It might be installed but might not be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a database connection string (DATABASE_URI), so the server is trying to connect to localhost.  Where are you hosting your MongoDB and where are you hosting your server?

In your index.js file, you need to include your database connection string:

```
var databaseUri = mongodb://...;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Of course finding problems in the code that you don't provide is a guess work but I think it is obvious from the error messages that you don't have a Mongo database listening on localhost:27017.